# mysql Cannot connect: invalid settings

Tags: php, mysql, apache, phpmyadmin

My phpMyAdmin stopped connecting to mySQL suddenly with the following error:

> Error MySQL said: Documentation
>
> Cannot connect: invalid settings.   phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the
>   MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check
>   the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure
>   that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of
>   the MySQL server.

I am running MAMP with php7 on a MAC.

- I have checked my config.inc.php setting and both user and password
  are set to root.
- I have checked the httpd.conf file and changed the port from 8888 to 80
- I have also reverted back on mamp controlpanel from php 7 to php
  5.6.10.

And always stopped apache and restarted between changes. None of these changes have had any effect. Really don't understand why it suddenly stopped working. 
I can still access mysql from Sequel Pro and MySQLWorkbench.

Thankful for any suggestions :)

Comment: Have you checked the status of MySQL server and tried connecting through console ?

Comment: uninstall-> reinstall, often a quicker way to fix anything

Comment: do you have more than one mysql instances running?

Comment: Since not long ago, you cannot log to phpmyadmin with the mysql root user. You need to duplicate root privilege to a new user typically called phpmyadmin: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/763336/cannot-enter-phpmyadmin-as-root-mysql-5-7. Even if it's a ubuntu forum you will understand the fix.

Comment: have checked that I have only one instance running and that I have the complete permissions on the mamp folder